# Drawing rectangle on the canvas in html 5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am  using html5 canvas and drawing rectangles on the canvas with the following code,

```
   function drawRectangle(mouseX,mouseY)
  {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(25,25,100,100);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
```

I am getting rectangle on the canvas,but the problem is
  Within that rectangle multiple lines is coming as the border.I dont want those lines.
  Please suggest me.

Comment: any images to show? because it may be because y ou may have added some other effects in there as well, Put your complete js code to get help

Comment: If you don't want a stroke then just eliminate `ctx.stroke()`. What do you mean by 'multiple lines'?  As @ShekharPankaj says we'll need more code.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use fillRect?

```
function drawRectangle(mouseX,mouseY)
{
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillRect(25,25,100,100);
}
```